# invalid_token_response An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, spring-security-oauth2

I have added Azure AD as an authentication server but it is showing me the following error

> [invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]

- Springboot: 2.5.8
- Azure version: 3.10.0

my application.properties:

```
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.provider=azure-ad
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.client-id=<Client_id>
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.client-secret=<Client_secret>
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.scope=openid, profile
 spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure-client.client-authentication-method=post
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure-ad.authorization-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure-ad.token-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure-ad.jwk-set-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.azure-ad.user-name-attribute=name
 server.forward-headers-strategy=native
 logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

And SecurityConfig class:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
     @Override
     protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {    
         http.authorizeRequests()
                 .antMatchers( "/oauth2/**", "/login/**" ).permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
                 .and()
                 .oauth2Login()
                 .defaultSuccessUrl( "/home" );
    
     }
 }
```

And Controller:

```
 @RestController
 public class HomeController {
    
     @GetMapping( "home" )
     public String home( @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "claims['name']") String name ) {
         return String.format( "Hello %s!  welcome to the Security app", name);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Work around

**Solution 1:**
Make sure you have entered the correct **TenantID**, **ApplicationID** and **Application_Secret**, and the Group name in the `application.properties` file

**and also the scopes your app is requesting have been configured (if admin consent is required, please grant it) in Azure Portal.**

**Solution 2:**
Try with changing the  the azure endpoints from v2 to v1. This is done by changing the endpoints

e.g. http://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
becomes http://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/authorize as indicated in the [v1 & v2 comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

For more information about v1 refer this  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-overview)

For more details refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303916/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-token-response-when-exchanging-an-authorization-code):

Comment: thanks for the reply, the actual issue is I had added the wrong client secret, and after adding the correct secret it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error `invalid_token_response` while updating to Spring Boot 3 and Spring security 6.
The solution is to correct the property

`spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.<id>.client-authentication-method` and set it to `client_secret_post` instead of `post`.

`post` does not exist (any more). Compare to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/ClientAuthenticationMethod.html#CLIENT_SECRET_POST

Comment: In my case `post` works

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue about that problem while deploying the app to AKS Cluster.
We added this default property in app.yml. Because `post` doesn't work.

> client-authentication-method: client_secret_basic

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. In my case it was on a production environment where it worked before. The issue was the secret expired. Issued a new secret token, updated it on and application.properties and restarted the app.